# JavaScript (match) function is not working with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below-mentioned code is not  working with internet explorer and working with Chrome

```
 var serchkeyword = "ko";
 var str = "koneru";
 var newstr = str.replace(new RegExp(serchkeyword , "gi"), (match) => `<span style=color:yellow>${match}</span>`);
```

While it reaches to 3rd line it not responding in IE and, working in Chrome, Can you please help me to get rid of this.

I think because of (math) it is not working.

When I use

```
var newstr = str.replace(new RegExp(serchkeyword , "gi"), '<span style=color:yellow>'+serchkeyword+'</span>');
```

It's working.

Comment: IE does not know how to handle arrow functions.  Use normal functions instead for IE

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you can you please write code for me below